# How do I get a clean version of a song in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music

I have a song in iTunes that is the unclean version with bad language in it and I'd like to be able to get the clean version without bad language in it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can't, unless you're okay by editing the song file by yourself, or if there's a clean version of the song (which I very doubt).

Comment: Tori - welcome to Ask Different. I've up-voted your question but I notice it has two down-votes. I'm guessing this is because you've used informal language (lol and smileys) but I'm new here too so I cannot be sure of that. It's always useful if people who down vote new member's questions explain why, especially since, at its heart, this seems an interesting question (and Tetsujin's is [an interesting answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214362/142445))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 choices, really.

1. Look for a clean version on the iTunes Store - one without the red E

[image]

2. Learn to edit your own music using something like [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org) to either duck the volume at the desired point, overdub a 'beep', or chop out that section entirely. There are plenty of tutorials on the Audacity site.